# How can I read the Chi2-distribution density graph?

Tags: probability

I would like to know how to interpret the density graph of Chi2...
simply like, why do the graphs run like they run??? I just don't get it. And I really don't want to brabble along like hypothesizing-- I'd like to understand :) Thanks[image: ![Chi2 density graph]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RQED.png)

Source: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-Quadrat-Verteilung

Comment: Your question is a bit muddled and sort of runs on -- it reads like you're asking something after having run in from outside and you're out of breath and haven't quite gathered your thoughts yet. Can you clarify what you want? It's not clear quite what you're asking for. Is it that you need help comprehending what a density function is? (Also, *brabble* was a new word for me ... apparently it means "*to argue stubbornly about trifles*" for anyone else wondering, though it's not clear how "hypothesizing" comes in there. I don't follow the intent of that sentence at all.)

Comment: The graph doesn't even give you a good view of the densities because f cuts off at 0.5 and x at 8.  If you carried x out to say 20 you would at least see how for k=9 the distribution is looking symmetric and bell shape showing that it is approaching a normal curve (central limit theorem in action).

Comment: I'm like: What is x? Does x at "1" (e.g. for k= 4)  mean, that it has a probability of 0.17 (or a density of 0.17 -> what is a density of 0.17?)?  Why does the blue graph slope upwards initially and then goes down after "2"? What do the degrees of freedom have to do with the sloping of the curve? Thanks! :)